# Text-Shadow Over_Ride in Global Class CSS

Tags: html, css

My text shadow is in the state of Override throughout my HTML / CSS3 Document.

Here are the tags:

```
html *,
#footerTextdetail {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 2px 2px 2px (0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
}
```

How to I ensure the Text-Shadow can display properly without being overrided.  I cannot locate the override, since the source of override is not documented with Google Chrome Inspection Tool Update Beta CSS/XGS.

Comment: Why there not "rgba" for second text-shadow?

Answer (score 0):

```
#footerTextdetail {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
}
```

Replace your code with this Remove html *

Answer (score 0):

Remove html * from your css code it is only reason for override

```
#footerTextdetail {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 2px 2px 2px (0, 0, 0,0.3) !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using **[universal selector(*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)**...

`html *`....means target all the elements inside the `<html>` tag...

...so `html *` is targeting all the elements, thats why all the elements getting the `text-shadow`. So better to remove it...

And also your `text-shadow` value is not valid...you need to use `rgba` in the second `text-shadow` and I dont think there is any need of `!important` rule...Try to avoid it...

```
#footerTextdetail {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```